# How to use Flash content in my Android application?

Tags: android, flash, obfuscation

I'm developing the Android application, and I need to know some details about using Flash technology - my company has a lot of Flash content which was developing 3 years. Now we decided to make an Android application, and we want to add this content to the application. But I have read some article which told that Android (Google) had decided to remove support of this technology. So, now I'm confused - will Flash work in my application for Android >=4.0? Also, please, tell me, are there any standart ways to obfuscate Android resources (We want to protect our unique content)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Flash does not work on Android devices. You might create an Adobe Air application to bring a Flash application into Android device.

However on the long run it might makes more sense to invest your time in creating an HTML5 replacement.

Sebastian

Comment: Thank you. But what do you know about obfuscation?

Comment: It depends on what you want to "obfuscate". Code or Content (video/audio/images). If you want to protect images a watermark might be the best protection. Audio/Video might need DRM to protect. Code might makes sense to obfuscate. Depending on what Scripting language you use you can find various solutions in the net. However the best might be still to code a native application and compile that to binaries.

Answer (score 0):

About obfuscate read this article... there are no problems to use it in your project Here is [a link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29)!